# Can the United States and Europe do the same as China did?

Tags: covid-19

I live in Korea. Korea is autonomously implementing measures equivalent to those of China. Everyone is avoiding collective action over social distances. If unavoidable, use a mask and practice hygiene thoroughly. When an infected person is found, the contact is quickly tracked and self-isolated. Fortunately, South Korea is a peninsula and North Korea is blocking the North, so it is actually an island nation. All guests arriving by air are primarily controlled at the airport. Is the US and Europe capable of corresponding measures?

Comment: Sounds like this is going to be opinion based answer.

Comment: @GrahamChiu No. I sincerely wonder what people on the mainland think about whether they can overcome. The results will make a judgment, but I am curious about how to judge when people in their own country evaluate it with various information.